# UIView: adding UIViewController's view as a subview and its removing

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, release, addsubview

I would like to ask what is the correct way to add and remove UIViewController's view as a child view.
So, having UIViewController initialized I can add its view to view hierarchy as follows:

```
UIViewController *myViewControler = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[someAnotherView addSubview:myViewController.view];
```

Question 1: Should I release myViewController.view after `addSubview:` call?

If I want to remove myViewController's view from view hierarchy I call `[myViewController.view removeFromSuperview];`

Question 2: How should I release myViewController instance in this case after its view removedFromSuperview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not need to release the view, the owning view controller will do this for you.
2. I normally put the declaration of myViewController in the header and then release and nil it when I am done with it (either somewhere in the normal flow or in the dealloc of the containing view controller).

Comment: regarding 2: if I just release myViewController its view will not be removed, if I have correct understanding... so in this case will it be correct to [myViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; and then [myViewController release]?

Comment: That is correct, remove the view and release the controller at the point you no longer need them.